# Namespace for :create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have models `Admin`, `User` and `Airport`.

And I want admins to `:create`, `:update` etc. airports, and users only to `:show` and `:index`. But for better reading and managing routes, I want `new_airport_path` to have link

```
domain.com/admin/airports/new
```

and for `airports_path`

```
domain.com/airports
```

I've made `namespace` in `routes.rb`

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :airports, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
end

resources :airports, only: [:show, :index]
```

But, when I go to `new_admin_airport_path` I see

> uninitialized constant Admin::AirportsController

So, if I move `airports_controller` to `admin` folder and rename it to `Admin::AirportsController`, I won't allow users to see it, and receive a error

> uninitialized constant AirportsController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `scope`:

```
scope '/admin' do
   resources :airports, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
end
```

Comment: I'd suggest moving these actions out into their own controller if you're doing authorization checking. That way, you can share that authorization checking between multiple controllers as D-side outlines.

Answer (score 5):

You may treat that **as an error, or as a hint**:

### you can make multiple controllers for a single resource

In fact, it's common practice.

If one and the same resource (model?) is treated differently in different parts of the website, these parts are best handled by separate controllers, since actions in these parts of the website may overlap. Say, `show` action for admins may show some extra information not visible to the rest. With the same controller you'd have to clutter the views with checks like `if @user.admin?`, with two different controllers it's easy to have two distinct sets of views.

Moreover, this makes access control much easier, since you can restrict access to the entire controller to a specific set of users (admins) without specifying the lists of specific actions if the controller is combined.

Answer (score 2):

You'll actually want to set up two AirportsControllers.  One will be `app/controllers/airports_controller.rb` and the other will be `app/controllers/admin/airports_controller.rb`  Put the appropriate actions into each controller.

Don't forget to check your `rake routes` to see what has actually been set up and whether it fits your goals.